# i am getting a CSRF Exceptionin html page within the below code

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
function startJob(id) {
    jQuery.get(servletURL, {
        ACTION: "START",
        ID: id
    }, function(jsonObject) {
        printAjaxResponse(jsonObject);
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: So I think you are not sending CSRF token.

Comment: yeah, i am new to this stuts .if we add CSRF token ,can we fix this issue ?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
function startJob(id) {
  jQuery.get(servletURL, {
    ACTION: "START",
      ID: id
   },{
   headers:{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}, function(jsonObject) {
      printAjaxResponse(jsonObject);
   }, "json");
}
```